# Responsive image gallery with unique URL per image?

Tags: media, javascript

I've been tasked to create a carousel that would have **a unique URL per panel**.

The panel would have to contain multiple pieces of info (each piece a link), and so would be views based.
the panels would have to be able to rotate.

Royal slider seems like it may be up to the task: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

My question is - are there any recommendations for other modules? module combos? custom script?

I'm using D7.23

Thanks!

Comment: What's a "Panel" in this context? Is it a cTools panel? Or an individual frame of the slider?

Comment: Sorry, in this case a "panel" will be one set of displayed content, which will have image and text elements

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [Flexislider](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider) module:

> Flex Slider module integrates the [Flex Slider library](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) with Drupal and several contributed modules which allows you to build responsive, resizable slideshows. Meaning the slideshows automatically adapt to the size of the browser window or device.

Some features of FlexSlider slideshows include:

- Touch enabled nagivation
- Keyboard navigation
- Configurable slide animations
- Multiple sliders per page

Demo available here: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider

> Library available at: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

And as far as the unique URL per panel thing is concerned I guess that depends upon how you creating the structure for slider, i.e while creating the structure for slider you can define the unique **id** attribute for each `li` as following:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li id="UNIQUE-ID1">
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="UNIQUE-ID2">
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="UNIQUE-ID3">
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

> Drupal also have the [royalslider library integration](https://drupal.org/project/royalslider) which integrates the [royal slider library](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

Comment: I've used flex slider and it's nice, and I've seen the mod for RoyalSlider - the critical piece I need help with is making sure that each panel displays a unique URL in the address bar so i can provide links to the different panel states. Is this something you can advise on?

Comment: I'm moving the conversation over to this thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89993/flexslider-and-hash-url

Comment: I'm planning on trying the royal slider mod on monday if I don't get feedback on this or my other thread - the key for me is the URL hash being available

Answer (score 0):

If you can style the slider yourself, then usually [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) is the most flexible way to go. It uses cycle.js by default but if you're good with Drupal and php code you can create a plugin for your Royal Slider.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same, but the critical point for me is having the unique URL for the unique content panel, since I have to let people link to each. How best can I handle this?

Comment: Any slider library with an API should be able to handle this. You would catch a querystring or a URL fragment using Javascript, and open the correct slide/panel/frame as the starting slide.

Comment: Hi Beebee, If you can point me to some examples I can look at I'd appreciate is. I don't know how to achieve this.